# SQLAlchemy range overlap query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

There are two columns datetimerange[] type.
How to write the following query in sqlalchemy?

SQL:

```
unnest(range_array_1) && unnest(range_array_2)
```

I tried this method, but it gives an error

```
session.query(table_1.id).filter(func.unnest(table_1.range_array_1).overlaps(func.unnest(table_2.range_array_2 )))

    
AttributeError: Neither 'Function' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'overlaps'
```